# Se me pierden las fotos con el paginator

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Cuando carga la pagina funciona bien me muestra las imágenes pero si pongo siguiente en el paginator las imágenes se pierden tengo la duda a que se debe esto.
Funciona bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al momento de click el paginador siguiente o el numero se pierde.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo la duda que pueda ser el `welcome/list/` que salto que ocurre hay

```html
public function list()
 {
  $this->load->library('pagination');
  $config['base_url']=base_url().'index.php/welcome/list';
  $config['uri_segement']=3;
  $config['per_page']=6;
  //Style
  $config['first_tag_open'] ='<li>';
  $config['first_tag_close'] ='</li>';
  $config['last_tag_open'] ='<li>';
  $config['last_tag_close'] ='</li>';
  $config['prev_tag_open'] ='<li>';
  $config['prev_tag_close'] ='</li>';
  $config['next_tag_open'] ='<li>';
  $config['next_tag_close'] ='</li>';
  $config['num_tag_open'] ='<li>';
  $config['num_tag_close'] ='</li>';
  $config['cur_tag_open'] ='<li class="active"><a href="#">';
  $config['cur_tag_close'] ='</a></li>';

  $page=$this->uri->segment(3,0);
  
  $data['post'] = $this->m->getPost($config['per_page'],$page);
  $config['total_rows']=$this->m->getTotalRow();
  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  $data['pagination']= $this->pagination->create_links();
  $this->load->view('list', $data);
 }
```

```html
<div class="item-image">
  <a href="<?php echo base_url('/index.php/welcome/jobdetails/'.$row->id_post); ?>">
  <img src="../assets/img/ico/<?php echo $row -> img; ?>" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
  </a>
</div>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien estare al tanto del post. Saludos

Comment: ya intestaste con `<img src="../../assets` o `<img src="<?= base_url()?>assets"`

Comment: Gracias me funciono :)